# Copying a range of columns within a row instead of entire row to another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty clueless on this stuff, just starting to play with it.  I have a code I got from a website, I customized it and it works great.  It looks at a value in column 12 (a numeric value) on a master sheet, in my case "invoice2" and then copies that entire row based on the column 12 value to the pre-created sheet matching that value in my workbook.  What I'd like is for it to only copy the row from columns A to H, not the entirety of columns A to L.  I cannot for the life of me figure out where to adjust that in this code.  Can anyone assist?

```
'<<<<  Create a new sheet for every Unique value or paste it below the existing data if the sheet exists  >>>>>

'This example copy all rows with the same value in the first column of
'the range to a new worksheet. It will do this for every unique value.
'The sheets will be named after the Unique value.
'If the sheet already exists the data will be pasted below the existing data on that worksheet.

'Note: this example use the function LastRow and SheetExists in the ModReset module

Sub Copy_To_Worksheets_2()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow and SheetExists
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim Lr As Long

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A11 is the top left cell of your filter range
'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
Set My_Range = Range("A12:L" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
My_Range.Parent.Select

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
   My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 12

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

With ws2
    'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
    My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
    Lrow = .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

        My_Range.Parent.Select
        'Filter the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
                                                        Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

        'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
        CCount = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Areas(1).Cells.count
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value: " & cell.Value _
                 & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                 & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
        Else
            'Add a new worksheet or set a reference to a existing sheet
            If SheetExists(cell.Text) = False Then
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set DestRange = WSNew.Range("A1")
            Else
                Set WSNew = Sheets(cell.Text)
                Lr = LastRow(WSNew)
                Set DestRange = WSNew.Range("A" & Lr + 1)
            End If

            'Copy the visible data to the worksheet
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With DestRange
                .Parent.Select
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select
            End With
        End If

        ' Delete the header row if you copy to a existing worksheet
        If Lr > 1 Then WSNew.Range("A" & Lr + 1).EntireRow.Delete

        'Show all data in the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

    Next cell

    'Delete the ws2 sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

If ErrNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
         & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
         & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
My_Range.Parent.Select
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With


End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function SheetExists(SName As String, _
                 Optional ByVal WB As Workbook) As Boolean
'Chip Pearson
On Error Resume Next
If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook
SheetExists = CBool(Len(WB.Sheets(SName).Name))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code slightly :) Now it yields what you wanted.

The current version of code:

```
'<<<<  Create a new sheet for every Unique value or paste it below the existing data if the sheet exists  >>>>>

'This example copy all rows with the same value in the first column of
'the range to a new worksheet. It will do this for every unique value.
'The sheets will be named after the Unique value.
'If the sheet already exists the data will be pasted below the existing data on that worksheet.

'Note: this example use the function LastRow and SheetExists in the ModReset module

Sub Copy_To_Worksheets_2()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow and SheetExists
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim Filter_Range As Range
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim DestRange As Range
Dim Lr As Long

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A11 is the top left cell of your filter range
'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
With ActiveSheet
    Set My_Range = .Range("A12:H" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    Set Filter_Range = .Range("L12:L" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    .Select
End With

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
    My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
        vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 12

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

With ws2
    'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
    Filter_Range.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
    Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

        My_Range.Parent.Select
        'Filter the range
        Filter_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & _
            Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

        'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
        CCount = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Areas(1).Cells.Count
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value: " & cell.Value _
                 & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                 & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
        Else
            'Add a new worksheet or set a reference to a existing sheet
            If SheetExists(cell.Text) = False Then
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set DestRange = WSNew.Range("A1")
            Else
                Set WSNew = Sheets(cell.Text)
                Lr = LastRow(WSNew)
                Set DestRange = WSNew.Range("A" & Lr + 1)
            End If

            'Copy the visible data to the worksheet
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With DestRange
                .Parent.Select
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select
            End With
        End If

        ' Delete the header row if you copy to a existing worksheet
        If Lr > 1 Then WSNew.Range("A" & Lr + 1).EntireRow.Delete

        'Show all data in the range
        Filter_Range.AutoFilter 'Field:=FieldNum

    Next 'cell

    'Delete the ws2 sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

If ErrNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
         & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
         & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
My_Range.Parent.Select
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    LastRow = sh.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End Function

Function SheetExists(SName As String, Optional ByVal WB As Workbook) As Boolean
'Chip Pearson
On Error Resume Next
If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook
SheetExists = CBool(Len(WB.Sheets(SName).Name))
End Function
```

Changes are basically related to the newly added `Filter_Range`. `My_Range` remains, but while the subroutine is processing, fields are no longer filtered according to the 12th column of `My_Range`. Now filter works on the first (the only) column of `Filter_Range`. In the code you can see assigned values for both of them.

```
Set My_Range = .Range("A12:H" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
Set Filter_Range = .Range("L12:L" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
```

`LastRow` function was also changed, now it has only one line:

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    LastRow = sh.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End Function
```

Try it out, it works! :)

Comment: Heh, that was the first thing I tried.  Didn't work. Gives me the error:

"Run-time error '1004' Application defined or object defined error" and when I look at my workbook is has created 'Sheet1" and in column A I have a list of my column L values copied.  That's all it does.